# Renaming APIs in swagger with Spring

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I understand that when documenting an API with Swagger in Spring, I can change the description for the API by adding `@Api` annotation, but when I add it as follows

```
@Api(value= "NEW_NAME", description="NEW_DESCRIPTION")
```

Only the description is changed, not the name.

as seen here

[image]

Further, I'm not sure where the default name and description are coming from, before adding the API, the name seems to be derived from the controller name, but the description; which to me looks natural and human like almost like hard coded String with capitalization and all.
I ran a search on the code, and I wasn't able to find those Strings. Where's Swagger getting those values from?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute you are looking for is: `tags`. So you can avoid grouping by controller name.

From Javadoc of `@Api` `tags`:

> Tags can be used for logical grouping of operations by resources or any other qualifier.

For example:

```
@Api(value = "/customers", tags = "customers", description = "Manage Customer")
```

By default Springfox creates API with name as `{controller-name}-controller` and description as `{Controller Name} Controller` (cf. [How to change the default Controller Name in Swagger Spring](https://kalliphant.com/swagger-spring-rest-controllername-change/) ).

Answer (score 3):

**Default -**
{controller-name}-controller
[image: {controller-name}-controller]

**For Custom Name Add -**
@Tag(name="YOUR CUSTOM NAME HERE")

on the Controller Class

Example -

```
@RestController
@Tag(name="1. Project Resource")
public class ProjectResource {...}
```

**Result -**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the current way to do this is:

```
@Api(description = "Manage cars", tags = { "Cars" })
```